# How to put jdom Document in Inputstream

Tags: java, inputstream, jdom

I use the following code to put a jdom document in InputStream:

```
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.setRootElement(root);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(doc);
    Result outputTarget= new StreamResult(outputStream);
    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
    InputStream inputstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

I get the followingerror on  `Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(doc);`: 
'DOMSource(org.w3c.dom.Node)' in 'javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource' cannot be applied to '(org.jdom.Document)'

How to solve this problem?

Comment: How the `xmlSource` related to the outputStream?

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: How you are using `xmlSource`? I can't find any relation with `outputTargets` or `inputStream` with  `xmlSource` in your code. Or you just need to fix the line `Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(doc);`?

Comment: I have edited the code. what I want to reach is to put xml document or root element in inputstream :)

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem by replacing DOMSource by JDOMSource

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier approach (assumes using JDOM API).

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.setRootElement(root);
XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
String docString = outputter.outputString(doc );
InputStream inputstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(docString .toByteArray());
```